# how to reload larger div after accessing smaller div

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I created three onclick trigger functions that trigger three separate    divs (sports, interactive, news) in a larger horizontal div ("main") . They        all show up initially but for some reason, the function only works after one click then I have to refresh the page. For example if I click trigger the sports function I have to refresh the page before I can use the news button. From there I have to refresh the page. How do I get the main div to reload before I trigger a second of third event? I've tried location.reload() but that doesn't seem to work.

```
     <div id="main">

     <div id="news">
    <h2 id="newsbtn"> News </h2>
    </div>  

    <div id="interactive">
    <h2 id="interactivebtn"> Interactive</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="sports">
    <h2 id="sportsbtn"> Sports </h2>
    </div>

    </div>

    JavaScript
    $( "#newsbtn" ).click(function() {
    $("#sports").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
    $("#interactive").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})


   $( "sportsbtn" ).click(function() {
   $("#interactive").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
   $("#news").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})


  $("#interactivebtn" ).click(function() {
  $("#sports").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
  $("#news").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})


   $( "#news" ).click(function() {
  $("#sports").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ),
   $("#interactive").fadeOut( "slow", "linear" );})
  ;})
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is fairly easy: after you've clicked one of the divs the two other divs fade out and hence they are invisible and not clickable. But there is no functionality in your code to redisplay the divs so you cannot click them ('cause they are not there).
You need to think of a way to redisplay the invisible divs (eg. using a fourth button) in order to make them visible and clickable again.

Comment: And that is exactly what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: What exactly? Don't you know how to add a function to redisplay the divs?